# Как выровнять содержимое button по вертикали если использовался float?

Tags: css

Заметил что у кнопок со свойством `float` содержимое немного вниз сдвинуто `vertical-align` и `line height` не работают. Как выровнять?

Comment: Покажите пример чтобы не гадать

Comment: код покажите? потому что так не понятно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А попробовали использовать `padding-top` и `padding-bottom`? Должно работать.